# Implement Wakelock

Tags: android, wakelock

I have a `Service` which has two `TimerTask` which run on frequency of 2 minutes (set by user preference from 2 to 30 minutes.) .

Now this works fine, but when the phone goes to sleep (lights off and phone under lock) this does not work as per expectations. So I think I need to implement wakelock for this..

If so, what is the best way to use wakelock.

I found that we can use `Alarmmanager` also ..

Please help and also where in the cose should i implement this ..(inside the oncreate methos or the class extending timetask).

Andoid 2.2 taget version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally using Wakelocks is a very, very rare need. It can have a significant impact on battery life and it's easy to make error, in that case wakelock will not be released at all.

For your purpose the AlarmManager ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html ) is the ideal solution. It guarantees that no sleep will be performed during your execution, but between this executions(2 or 30 minutes) device can go to sleep and save a good amount of battery. System will wake-up when it's time to execute your next execution.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks a ton Alex .. i too think that using AlarmManager is the best option if possible can you point out some good examples for the same and also should i use it inside my timertask . ?

Comment: Seems the following example is ok: http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129 . So depending on what you do, you should either do it just inside Broadcast receiver, or start, for example, an IntentService from this receiver, if the task can take a long time.
 
Also I think that you have no need in TimerTask anymore, as it's completely different from AlarmManager approach and cannot be used with it.

Comment: what should i use instead of timertask .?

Comment: Just use the broadcast receiver in pair with AlarmManager. So basically move your operations from TimerTask to the broadcastReceiver and than schedule it's peiodical executions via AlarmManager

Comment: I have now used `Intent i = new Intent(this, DataSyncTask.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), SYNC_ALARM_MANAGER_ID, i, 0);
  am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000L, 2 * 60 * 1000L, pi);`

But this doesn't call the reciever (ClassDataSyncTask extends BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: Is your broadcastReceiver registered in Manifest by 'receiver' tag?

Comment: Are you sure that Intent 'i' is correct for sending broadcast? Will it work if you'll just use sendBroadcast(i)? Because I'm not 100% sure that direct component name in intent will work for the Broadcast, maybe you'll have to spicify an action for it, so receiver would listen to it with intentFilter, and Intent i will be new Intent("your_action");

Comment: Does My class DataSyncTask (class extending to BroadcastReceiver) needs to be a public class .. ?

Comment: For sure, if it's declared in XML

Comment: okay ..  i think that is the problem  ... actually this class was as a inner class ..  so might be that was the problem ..

Comment: if it is a public static inner class - it will not be a problem, I think

Comment: Thanks a lot ..  i am still working on it .. the receiver is now being called butnot working as per expectations ... anyways thanks